# Can't get attribute 'MyScaler' on <module '__main__'>

Tags: python, module, attributeerror

I have a class in one of my notebooks as below :

```
class MyScaler(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self,columns,with_mean=True,with_std=True,copy=True):
        self.scaler = StandardScaler(copy,with_mean,with_std)
        self.columns = columns
        self.mean_ = None
        self.var_ = None

    def fit(self,X,y=None):
        self.scaler.fit(X[self.columns],y)
        self.mean_ = np.array(np.mean(X[self.columns]))
        self.var_ = np.array(np.var(X[self.columns]))
        return self

    def transform(self,X,y=None,copy=None):
        initial_col_order = X.columns
        X_scaled = pd.DataFrame(self.scaler.transform(X[self.columns]),columns=self.columns)
        X_not_scaled = X.loc[:,~X.columns.isin(self.columns)]
        return pd.concat([X_not_scaled,X_scaled],axis=1)[initial_col_order]
```

I am pickling this class as :

```
with open('Custom_Scaler','wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(MyScaler,file)
```

I have another module 'LogReg_Absent_Module' where i am trying to un-pickle this file. I have also defined this class in that module as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pickle
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

#The custom scaler that only scales the non-dummy value columns.
class MyScaler(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self,columns,with_mean=True,with_std=True,copy=True):
        self.scaler = StandardScaler(copy,with_mean,with_std)
        self.columns = columns
        self.mean_ = None
        self.var_ = None

    def fit(self,X,y=None):
        self.scaler.fit(X[self.columns],y)
        self.mean_ = np.array(np.mean(X[self.columns]))
        self.var_ = np.array(np.var(X[self.columns]))
        return self

    def transform(self,X,y=None,copy=None):
        initial_col_order = X.columns
        X_scaled = pd.DataFrame(self.scaler.transform(X[self.columns]),columns=self.columns)
        X_not_scaled = X.loc[:,~X.columns.isin(self.columns)]
        return pd.concat([X_not_scaled,X_scaled],axis=1)[initial_col_order]

#The class that we are going to use from here on to predict new data
class absenteeism_model():
    def __init__(self,model_file,scaler_file):
        with open('Absenteeism_Model','rb') as model_file,open('Custom_Scaler','rb') as scaler_file:
            self.log_reg = pickle.load(model_file)             #Load the previously saved model 
            self.scaler = pickle.load(scaler_file)             #and scaler.
            self.data = None
```

From a new notebook, when i try `model = absenteeism_model('Absenteeism_Model','Custom_Scaler')`

I get:

````
<ipython-input-66-8631c175353f> in <module>
----> 1 model = absenteeism_model('Absenteeism_Model','Custom_Scaler')

~\LogReg_Absent_Module.py in __init__(self, model_file, scaler_file)
    37         with open('Absenteeism_Model','rb') as model_file,open('Custom_Scaler','rb') as scaler_file:
    38             self.log_reg = pickle.load(model_file)             #Load the previously saved model
---> 39             self.scaler = pickle.load(scaler_file)             #and scaler.
    40             self.data = None
    41 

AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'MyScaler' on <module '__main__'>```
````

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why you pickle a class and not an object of that class

Comment: I tried pickling the object of the MyScaler class and i still get the AttributeError.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind showing the code of part where you have implemented your MyScaler.  What i think is the issue with the object of your MyScaler class while you are saving your scaler.

for example you have declared:

```
scaler = MyScaler(X)
```

then in this case you will pickle using following code:

```
 with open ('Custom_Scaler' , 'wb') as file: 
  pickle.dump(scaler, file)
```

See if this solves your issue.

Comment: If it doesn't help, try changing your scaler file with this file:https://github.com/Haaz123/Absenteeism_Prediction